# return the lowest number from an array with null values in visual basic

Tags: vba, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I've written a function that returns the minimum values of the 8 numerical values inputted through SSRS.

Problem is there is not always 8 values and when there isn't I receive an error in SSRS. i think this is because I'm feeding the function null values

I don't ever work with VB, is there anyone who can show me a work around?

The code used is below
enter code here

```
Function minimumReading(reading0 as String
                        ,reading1 as String 
                        ,reading2 as String
                         ...    7 as String)

Dim     a(7) as String
        a(0) = reading0
        a(1) = reading1
        ...
        a(7) = reading7
Dim max as string
    Dim min as string

max = a(3)
min = a(3)

Dim i as integer

for i = Lbound(a) to Ubound(a)
    if a(i) < min Then min = a(i)
next i

minimumReading =  min

End Function`
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain how the numerical values are "inputted through SRSS" - are they supplied from a parameter? If so is the parameter populated from a query, a list entered by the user etc.?

Comment: They are supplied through custom code in one of the cells of a report that I'm building. =Code.minimumReading(Fields!reading.Value,Fields!reading2.Value .. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to pass the 8 values as individual arguments?  It would be better form (also easier to maintain long run) to create a function that finds the minimum of an array (which might already exist)

If you must have it the way you have setup you can use this

```
Dim a() As String
ReDim a(0 To 0)
Dim i As Long
If reading0 <> vbNullString Then
    a(UBound(a)) = reading0
End If
If reading1 <> vbNullString Then
    ReDim Preserve a(LBound(a) To (UBound(a) + 1))
    a(UBound(a)) = reading1
End If
If reading2 <> vbNullString Then
    ReDim Preserve a(LBound(a) To (UBound(a) + 1))
    a(UBound(a)) = reading2
End If
...
```

Again my suggestion is to restructure your code.